How do you set a Parameter for an SSIS task in SQL Server Agent Job to Null when Required is set to False
When you first deploy a package and set up a job I can see some parameters are defaulted to NULL and it appears in italics so you know it is NULL value and not a NULL text. However, when you view the data by clicking on the edit button the field is blank. If you change the value to something other than Null to blank say (or simply do nothing other than click the ok button) you can never it get back to NULL. Is there some key combination trick to set it to Null??
Job Set up

SSIS - Visual Studio


What is a "SQL Server Job"? Do you mean a SQL Server Agent Job? Those don't have parameters.

Perhaps Null is invalid value and you I wont be able to click the ok on the step until it has a value - I will let you know.

Null's are excepted as valid values and my job runs.

Try CTRL + 0 (zero, not "O"). When using SSMS to "Edit Top 100" rows of a table, CTRL+0 sets the field to NULL.

That works for editing table data not SQL Server Agent Job Parameters. Was actually the first thing I tried hence why I mentioned above "Is there some key combination trick ...".

Only work around I have is to delete the step and redo just would be nice to know it could be done.

I also remember in the old sql server versions you could not even enter blank without it spitting at you and you had to enter a space and thus truncate in your code, I have not come across that issue in 2019 yet. So, I am not sure if NULL is a 2019 server thing or a bit earlier.

I'd suggest using null string text and alter your formula to convert to a real null.
ExportFileNamePrefix == "null" ? null(DT_WSTR) : ExportFileNamePrefix

I was actually using it in a c# script task and to be honest it is not the end of the world if the value for this particular parameter is either null, blank or a space as I can use: ( + "").Trim() in c#.
I was more thinking about say if I was using a job parameter to pass into a call to a stored procedure and the proc excepted Nulls how would you do it, if I deployed the package with a set value initially there seems no way to set it to Null in the job. I guess your idea would work or similar concept in a script task.
